# Opengl - what is gl.h - how to write a very simple gl app using newest api

Tags: c++, opengl

ow to write a very simple gl app using newest api.
And what is gl.h where to downlaod it, how to use it

Comment: Your question is really lacking lots of useful information: what language, what platform, what do you want to do, etc.

Comment: answered in your other question about header files.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very up-to-date Wiki which also explains how to get started writing software with the new OpenGL 3.0 API:

http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started

Answer (score 1):

Start here: http://www.opengl.org/code/category/C22

Comment: But where is GL dicrectory, I see many tutorial include gl/gl,h but i don't know where to download it